# Adding jar library to Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a project developed in Maven. I want to add new jar file to classpath. I added new dependency in pom.xml file:

> ```
> <dependency>
> <groupId>mzmatch</groupId>
> <artifactId>mzmatch</artifactId>
> <version>1.2.13</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

All the jar libraries are in lib directory. The name of all the libraries matches artifactId-version.jar and their locations are (inside lib directory) groupId/artifactId/version. So I did the same for my mzmatch-1.2.13.jar file.

Apart from adding new dependency in pom file, I added my jar to class-path in Manifest.MF file. But the software still doesnt see my jar. What else should I do? Or I didnt add my library correctly?

Comment: um... so you want to add new jar file to classpath. why are you adding it to pom.xml then, instead of classpath? Do you want to install your jar into maven system? if so, have you taken a look at mvn install?

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming this is a jar that you developed, and now want Maven to pick it up as a dependency.  To do that, you need to install it to your local Maven repository.  Not the lib directory of your project, but the .m2 directory (probably off your home directory in Windows).  You probably want to run this from the command line:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=mzmatch -DartifactId=mzmatch -Dversion=1.2.13 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Take a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html) for more info.

EDIT 1: I'm assuming that the OP is not working within a larger team.  If the dependency were required by anyone else within a development team, then it would need to be deployed to a shared internal artifact repository, like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview/).  These applications have a page for uploading your artifacts.

EDIT 2: Adding a library as a dependency in your pom.xml ensures that Maven will have it on the classpath when it compiles the code for this new project.  If you want it there at runtime (say, if you want an executable jar), and you want to have it in the Class-Path entry in your `MANIFEST.MF`, then you could have Maven [set it up](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html).  That still doesn't put the `mzmatch-1.2.13.jar` file in the same directory as your new project.  If you don't want to do that manually, again Maven can [do it for you](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html).

Comment: if the OP is working with other developers, that file should be deployed to a shared repository, not installed into the local file repository.

Comment: @jtahlborn Assuming OP is working locally.  Put a note in about internal repos, though.

Comment: thanks.  you don't need to use the repository page, though, you would most likely use the `deploy:deploy-file` goal.

Comment: I installed the jar in repository, how can I generate new Manifest file? I added my jar to class-path in manifest file and build new jar package, however, it still does not see my new jar. I don't know why it does not see it ((

Comment: Edited to add some more info.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Build an executable .jar?  Please add some more specifics to your question.